# Has anyone compiled a book of at the Sahaba and authentic/trustworthy scholars narrating dreams of seeing the Prophet (saw)?

Tags: authenticity, uloom-al-hadith, sahaba, dream, tashahhud

Every once in a while I hear about or read a story where a certain scholar saw the Prophet (saw) in a dream.  I was just wondering if anyone has written a book collecting these experiences narrated by the Sahaba and trustworthy scholars from the past.  For example, I came across this narration below when reading about tashahhud:

Abu Eisa (Tirmidhi) said: There are narrations on this topic from Ibn ‘Umar, Jabir, Abu Musa, and ‘Aishah (may Allah be pleased with them). Abu ‘Eisa said: The Hadith of Ibn Mas’ud (may Allah be pleased with him) has been reported from him through other routes, and it is the most correct Hadith [reported] from the Prophet (peace be upon him), about At-Tashahhud. This is acted upon according to most of the people of knowledge among the Companions of the Prophet (peace be upon him) and those after them among the Tabi’in. It is the saying of Sufyan Ath-Thawri, Ibn Al-Mubarak, Ahmad, and Ishaq. Ahmad bin Muhammad bin Musa narrated to us: ‘Abdullah bin Al-Mubarak informed us, from Ma’mar, from Khusaif who said: “I saw the Prophet (peace be upon him) in a dream. I said: ‘0 Messenger of Allah (peace be upon him)! The people disagree over the Tashahhud.’ He (peace be upon him) said: ‘Follow the Tashahhud of Ibn Mas’ud.”